# CSS, floating boxes are bumping each other

Tags: html, css

I am a noob, so my code is pretty simple:

```
    .pictureBoxWrapper1 {
    width: 225px;
    /* background: silver; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:7px;
    float:left;
    border:dotted;
    margin-right:10px;

}
```

Unfortunately it is still giving me some unexpected results like this:

[image]

as you can see I have two of the boxes on the left that are "bumping" into each other.

Is there some way that I can make my box not expand no matter what text/images are in it?

**UPDATE:**
Pastebin for entire CSS file
http://pastebin.com/tp1WS4r3

Comment: Can you post your code for that image? Since they mostly work, I suspect that some of them are missing the pictureBoxWrapper1 class or are inheriting some other properties.

Comment: You can give the boxes a minimum height eg: `min-height: 200px`

Comment: the link is still missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your images are of more size. You can try restricting the image size either by using style in image tag,

`<img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:300px; max-height:300px;" src="...">`

or through css

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="..." alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the image so that all are the same: http://s27.postimg.org/3ss9bu583/Screen_Shot_2014_11_10_at_8_01_41_AM.png It still does not work

Comment: Try posting the part of the HTML where you create these boxes. It should actually work if done correctly in HTMl

Answer (score 3):

```
max-height: 200px;
```

They'll not get bigger than 200px

Answer (score 0):

i think you should .fix your image height to 160px and also set box height to 308px;
for confirm and detail solution pls online your code if possible.

Comment: The page is with a LOT of code and external files, I am using Mamp so its on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use min-height or max-height inside your css like:

```
max-height: 200px;
min-height: 200px;
```

or clear the float after multiple of 3 elements, example

after the 3rd element add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

after the 6th element add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

after the 9th element add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

and so on and so on

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Making them the same size would help - but not if they aren't the same size.

For multi-sized boxes, you can use CSS3 columns instead of "float:left" boxes to arrange them in a loose grid.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

The columns class is designed to allow paragraph text to flow in columns - such as with a newspaper - but can be hijacked by applying the same style to discreet boxes.

First create a wall container for the boxes - which I will call bricks.

```
<div class="wall">
</div>

.wall {
  width: 100% !important;
  column-count: 3 !important;  
  column-gap: 25px;
}
```

Next you need a brick. But there is a problem! You will probably want to add a margin to the bottom of each brick to space them out. Unfortunately CSS columns are a bit quirky and will actually break a margin into the next column - leaving gaps at the top of some columns but not others. This is why you will need two containers for each brick. Like so:

```
<div class="outer-brick">
  <div class="inner-brick">
    Any contents ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Add a "nobreak" style to the outer brick - so that you can add a margin for the inner brick that stays with it.

```
.wall .outer-brick {
  display: block-inline !important;  
  /* prevent brick's padding splitting across columns */
  break-inside: avoid !important;  
  /* !useful "margin" between inner-bricks to match column-gap   */
  padding-bottom: 25px; 
}
.wall .outer-brick .inner-brick {
  /* CSS3: border and padding taken away from width */
  box-sizing: border-box !important;  
  /* !useful for contents, but not important */
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

That's it. Even with very different sized boxes, they will be evenly arranged, both horizontally and vertically, in columns. The more you have the better it looks.

See demo with randomly generated bricks at http://codepen.io/timitee/pen/wWRgqk